# "Uncaught reference error: initialize is not defined" when combining markers and driving directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I'm combining about 2000 markers from a JSON object with a driving directions tool. No matter what I try, I keep running into an initialize problem.

Attempts:

1. When I delete the "$(function(){" at the top and the related brackets at the bottom, my $('#mapall').change(function() doesn't work.
2. When I delete the body tag's "onload="initialize()">", the console gives me a "ReferenceError: calcRoute is not defined. This seems to be related to my jquery buttons (code below):

   ```
   $("#showmapview").click(function() {
   $("#map-form-page").hide();
   $("#map-route-page").show();
   window.location.hash = '#new-map-page';
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   });
   ```

Here is my JS. My HTML body includes body onload="initialize()"

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(function(){
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;            
        var arrMarkers = [];
        var arrInfoWindows = null;

        function clearOverlays() {
          if (arrMarkers) {
            for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
              arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }
          }
        }

        function showOverlays() {
          if (arrMarkers) {
            for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
              arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
            }
          }
        }

        $('#mapall').change(function() {
         if( $('#mapall').attr("checked")) {
                  showOverlays();
                  }
                  else  {
                  clearOverlays();
                  }
        });

    function initialize() {
          var rendererOptions = {
          CODE
         };

          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
          CODE HERE
            }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        $.getJSON( "CODE HERE", {}, function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
        var loc = item.masterlocation;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(+loc.latitude, +loc.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: loc.nickname,
        });
        arrMarkers.push(marker);

          CODE
          });
                    });

          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

     ENDS INITIALIZE

        function calcRoute() {
          CODE HERE

          var request = {
              origin: start,
              destination: end,
              waypoints: waypts,
              optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              var route = response.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");

              CODE HERE
            }

                STATUS WARNINGS HERE


          });
        }   
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
    });             
    </script>
```

**EDIT 1**

Based on @bnz's comments, I've reordered my code and deleted the body onload. Here is the new code, but now, if I uncheck the checkbox and then try to check it again, the markers will not reappear. There are no errors in the console, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
    var directionsDisplay;
    var map;            

        function clearOverlays() {
          if (arrMarkers) {
            for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
              arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }
          }
        }

        function showOverlays() {
          if (arrMarkers) {
            for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; ++i ) {
              arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
            }
          }
        }

        $('#mapall').change(function() {
         if( $('#mapall').attr("checked")) {
                  showOverlays();
                  }
                  else  {
                  clearOverlays();
                  }
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
        });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var arrMarkers = [];
        var arrInfoWindows = null;

    function initialize() {
          CODE
        }

    function calcRoute() {
          CODE
        }; 

</script>
```

** EDIT 2 **

I've solved the problem where the checkbox would not turn on and off the markers. For some reason, the configuration of my javascript required that I use

```
    arrMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
```

and

```
    arrMarkers[i].setVisible(true);
```

Since my original question dealt with the initialize function and @bnz's comments helped me resolve this problem, crediting the answer to @bnz. Hopefully, others who are unable to get the arrMarkers to work with setMap(null) will be able to use this method.

Comment: Actually your initialize() function cant be seen, because its needed during load and your providing this after the load (ondomready). On top you dont need the onload method, because your are having an eventlistener for it defined. This event listener should not be located in the initialize() function as it looks now.

Comment: Hi, BNZ! Sorry, I'm a little confused. What should I move where? I think you're saying 1) delete the `<body "onload="initialize()">` but when I do this, I get a "ReferenceError: calcRoute is not defined." Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or, did you mean the initialize() function in the javascript tag?

Comment: i meant the onload method in the body-tag. you are calling initialize during your last line of js. can you share (some) of your markers in a json file? if we have that, i will take a look and try to make it work.

Comment: Hi, BNZ. I can't provide the actual JSON file, but here is some formatted data if it helps: `[{"masterlocation":{"latitude":"32.701415","nickname":"Point 1","id":100001,"longitude":"-96.767578"}}{"masterlocation":{"latitude":"32.632075","nickname":"Point 2","id":100002,"longitude":"-96.402283"}}]` The site is Ruby on Rails and I am loading the map page within another layout as framed content. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: No, i dont think so thats related to the markers / webservice /json. I would say that the error you are asking for is initiated by the onload call in your body tag. 2nd point is the google dom listener will be seen when the dom is ready, and that its too late. But i would say here is the critical point, the initialize function should not be a port of the dom ready statement, because you will need it during the load, as well as the listener for it - this should be basically the question to your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33598/discussion-between-kdp-and-bnz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JS stuff to initialize the map / handlers properly. 
Just copy + paste.

http://heidegluehen.com/bnz/17668427/

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var arrMarkers = [];

$(function(){
console.log('dom ready');

function clearOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; i++ ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

function showOverlays() {
  if (arrMarkers) {
    for( var i = 0, n = arrMarkers.length; i < n; i++ ) {
      arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

$('#mapall').change(function() {
 if( $('#mapall').prop("checked")) {
          showOverlays();
          }
          else  {
          clearOverlays();
          }
});

$('#end').change( function(){
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
});
});

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

function addMarker(location){
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
      });
arrMarkers.push(marker);
}  

 var jqxhr = $.getJSON('points.json', function(data) {
 console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function( i, item ) {
        console.log('hello');
        var loc = item.masterlocation;

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(+loc.latitude, +loc.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: loc.nickname,
        });
        arrMarkers.push(marker);
        });
        });

jqxhr.complete(function() { console.log( "json loaded" ); });       

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
      {
      addMarker(event.latLng);
      });      
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

- own markers can be hidden
- markers set by mouse or from a webservice
- you have to add the directions panel

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I used `arrMarkers[i].setVisible(false);` and `arrMarkers[i].setVisible(true);` instead of `setMap(map)` and setMap(null)` because my markers kept getting disassociated. My version works for me, but it was based on the above. Thanks!